# A rule of thumb to know which commands break in sudo?

Tags: command-line, sudo

There are some commands like `cd` or `ll` that if I run them as `sudo`, their execution just "breaks".

What is a rule of thumb to know which commands will "break" this way when a `sudo` command precedes them?

This data can help me and other newcomers to code stabler scripts.

Comment: Shell builtins and aliases?

Comment: Anything `root` may not have access to (e.g. encrypted volumes, remote NFS shares...)

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed as being  *too broad*. I think
[my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/354152/22812) provides a
reasonably comprehensive “rule of thumb” for determining whether a command will run as the user might expect it to run with `sudo`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only **external commands** can be run by `sudo`.

### Sudo

The `sudo` program forks (start) a new process to launch an external command with the effective privileges of the superuser (or another user if the `-u` option is used). That means that no commands that are internal to the shell can be specified; this includes shell keywords, builtins, aliases, and functions.

The best way to find out if a command is available as an external command (and not internal to the shell) is to run `type -a command_name` which displays all locations containing the specified executable.

#### Example 1: Shell builtin

In this case, the `cd` command is only available as a shell builtin:

```
$ type -a cd
cd is a shell builtin
```

It fails when you try to run it with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo cd /
sudo: cd: command not found
```

#### Example 2: Alias

In this case, the `ls` command is external – but an alias with the same name has also been created in the user’s shell.

```
$ type -a ls
ls is aliased to `ls -F --color'
ls is /bin/ls
```

If I was to run `sudo ls`, it would not be the alias that runs as the superuser; if I wanted the `-F` option, it would have to be explicitly included as an option, i.e., `sudo ls -F`.

#### Example 3: Shell builtin and external command

In this case, the `pwd` command is provided as both a shell builtin and an external command:

```
$ type -a pwd
pwd is a shell builtin
pwd is /bin/pwd
```

In this case, the external `/bin/pwd` command would run with `sudo`:

```
$ sudo pwd
/home/anthony
```

Other examples of commands that are often provided as both shell builtins and external commands are  `kill`, `test` (`[`) and `echo`.

### Run internal shell commands with sudo

If you really want to run a shell builtin with superuser privileges, you’d have to launch a shell as the external command. E.g., the following command runs `bash` as the superuser with the `cd` builtin command provided as a command line option:

```
$ sudo bash -c "cd /; ls"
bin   etc   lib  media  mnt  ntp.peers  proc  sbin     share  sys
tmp  var boot  dev  home  lost+found  misc   net  opt … …
```

Note: Aliases can not be passed as commands to Bash using its `-c` option.

## Shell redirection

Another issue to watch out for is that shell redirection takes place in the context of the current shell. If I try to run `sudo /bin/echo abc > /test.file`, it won’t work. I get `-bash: /test.file: Permission denied`. While the echo command runs with superuser privileges, it prints its output to my current (non-privileged) shell and, as a regular user, I don’t have permission to write to the `/` directory.

One work-around for this is to use `sudo` to launch a new shell (similar to the above example):

```
sudo bash -c "echo abc > /test.file"
```

In this case, the ouptut redirection takes place in the context of the privileged shell (which does have permission to write to `/`).

Another solution is to run the `tee` command as the superuser:

```
echo abc | sudo tee /test.file
```

Comment: This is a very good answer, but the first statement is false. You need to run `kill` with `sudo` to stop processes started by another user.

Comment: @Bruno9779 In that case, you're running an external `kill` command (provided by the `util-linux` package on most GNU/Linux systems). In fact, I've already mentioned `kill` it in my *Example 3*. Rather than downvote incomplete/misleading answers, I thought I'd add a better one.

Answer (score 0):

`cd` or `ll` is not a program, but in fact it is a built-in command in shell. You can view all the available built-in commands by using the following command.

> compgen -b

`sudo` will not work with all these commands.

Comment: No. `ll` is an alias

Comment: Also it is not true at all that all builtins will not work with sudo. EG: `pwd` `true` `kill`

Comment: @Bruno9779 the versions you run with `sudo` are the standalone executables. The built-in versions do not run with `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

`ll` does not work with sudo because it is an alias. Aliases do not work with sudo, as you don't get an interactive shell with sudo (unless asked specifically)

`cd` is a different case, since it doesn't make sense to change to a directory you don't have permission with sudo.

As suggested **many** builtins will not work with sudo, but others do, most notably `kill`. You need to run `sudo kill <pid>` to kill a process started by an user different than yours.

Comment: Even when the `ll` alias is defined in root's `.bashrc`, `sudo ll` reports `command not found`, because `sudo <command>` (or `sudo -i <command>`, or `sudo -s <command>`) doesn't start an interactive shell.

Comment: You are right, aliases don't work either way. I have edited my answer

Comment: The versions you run with `sudo` are the standalone executables. The built-in versions do not run with `sudo`. At all. For one example of a difference between a built-in and its corresponding standalone, try `cd /tmp; mkdir a; ln -s a b; cd b; pwd; /bin/pwd`