# What is `/usr/bin/cd`?

Tags: bash

I suggested using `which` to confirm whether a command works only as a [shell builtin or alias](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/354119/a-rule-of-thumb-to-know-which-commands-break-in-sudo#comment627380_354119).  `cd` is an example of a command that works as a shell builtin.  It would be much harder to implement the same function as a binary...

So why does my Fedora system have a binary `/usr/bin/cd`?  It doesn't implement the magic necessary to affect the shell (parent process) working directory, to match the behaviour of the `cd` builtin.  My Debian 8 system doesn't have `/usr/bin/cd`.

```
$ command -v sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
$ command -v cd
cd
$ which sudo
/usr/bin/sudo
$ which cd
/usr/bin/cd
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/cd
bash-4.3.43-4.fc25.x86_64
$ (. /etc/os-release && echo $PRETTY_NAME)
Fedora 25 (Workstation Edition)
$ pwd
/home/alan
$ cd /home && pwd
/home
$ /usr/bin/cd /home/alan && pwd
/home
$ cd --help
bash: cd: --: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|[-P [-e]] [-@]] [dir]
```

The full list of binaries provided by the bash package is

> $ rpm -q --dump bash|grep /usr/bin|cut -f 1 -d ' '|cut -f 4
>
> alias
>   bash
>   bashbug
>   bashbug-64
>   bg
>   cd
>   command
>   fc
>   fg
>   getopts
>   hash
>   jobs
>   read
>   sh
>   type
>   ulimit
>   umask
>   unalias
>   wait

Comment: Once upon a time, when I was a student, we were assigned a work to write a shell. At some point, I thought it was unneeded to implement a built-in `cd` command, since there was a `cd` executable somewhere… Then I understood how wrong I was. Anyway, there was also a `cd` executable in Solaris, and I still have no idea how it might be useful…

Comment: See also [#820192](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=820192).

Comment: See also [Why not use "which"? What to use then?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249)